# WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:

Tags: nodejs, angular, socket, socket.io, websocket

Estoy tratando de usar sockets con [socket.io](https://socket.io/) en Node js y Angular 
Me aparce el siguiente mensaje WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:

El codigo de Node js lo tengo de la siguiente manera:
Puerto: http://localhost:3000

```
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

const serverHttp = require("http").Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(serverHttp, {
   cors: {
      origin: true,
      credentials: true,
      methods: ["GET", "POST"],
   },
 });

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
console.log("User connected");

socket.on("test", () => {
   console.log("Test event");
 });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

Y en Angular lo tengo de la siguente manera:
Es un servicio que a su vez se esta usando en un componente.
Puerto: http://localhost:4200

```
export class SocketService {
public io = io('http://localhost:3000', {
  withCredentials: true,
  autoConnect: true,
  transports: ['websocket'],
  upgrade: false,
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  reconnectionDelay: 1000,
  reconnection: true,
  reconnectionAttempts: 10,
  agent: false,
});

constructor() {
  this.io.emit('test');
 }
```

}